# Maximum number of tasks supported in AUTOSAR

Tags: autosar

**What is the maximum number of tasks supported in AUTOSAR compliant systems?**

In Linux, I can check the maximum process IDs supported to get the maximum number of tasks supported.

However, I couldn't find any source that states the maximum number of tasks supported by AUTOSAR.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to vary. I found that [ETAS RTA offers 1024 tasks](https://www.etas.com/download-center-files/products_RTA_Software_Products/RTA-OS_PDS_PPCE200WR_v5.1.22.pdf)*, whereas Vector's MICROSAR OS has 65535.

For task handling, OSEK/ASR provides the following functions:

```
StatusType ActivateTask (TaskType TaskID)
StatusType TerminateTask (void)
StatusType Schedule (void)
StatusType GetTaskID (TaskRefType TaskID)
StatusType GetTaskState (TaskType TaskID, TaskStateRefType State)
```

*Link might change in future, but it is easy to search ETAS page directly for manuals etc.: https://www.etas.com/en/products/download_center.php

Comment: Thank you so much, Ludwig! This is really helpful! I'm wondering if there is any RTOS supporting up to 512 tasks or less? I feel that the real-time systems usually do not have so many tasks.

Comment: Mike, Micrium II has a limitation of 255 but no OSEK API. https://www.micrium.com/rtos/rtos-comparison/ -- I bet you'll find many more RTOS withless than 512 tasks. The RTOS might allow you N tasks, but implementations with >>20 tasks is not typical.

Comment: Ludwig, thank you so much for the useful information! I totally understand that "The RTOS might allow you N tasks, but implementations with >>20 tasks is not typical.". Is there any study or reference discussing the practical number of tasks in real-world systems?

Comment: Fyi Vector's Microsar OS: Maximum number of tasks: 65535; Another thing to consider is the concept of "Runnables", search for this.

Comment: New link to PDF: https://www.etas.com/download-center-files/products_RTA_Software_Products/RTA-OS_PDS_PPCE200WR_v5.1.22.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Well, we are still in an embedded automotive world and not on a PC.
There is usually a tradeoff between the number of tasks you have and what it takes to schedule them and what RAM/ROM and runtime resources your configuration uses.

As already said, if you just need a simple timed loop with some interrupts in between, one task may be ok. 
It might be also enough, to have e.g. 3 tasks running at 5ms, 10ms and 20ms cycle. But you could also schedule this in simple cases like this with a single 5ms task:

```
TASK(TASK_5ms)
{
    static uint8 cnt = 0;
    cnt++;
    // XXX and YYY Mainfunctions shall only be called every 10ms
    // but do a load balancing, that does not run 3 functions every 10ms
    // and 1 every 5ms, but only two every 5ms
    if (cnt & 1)  
    {
        XXX_Mainfunction_10ms();
    }
    else 
    {
        YYY_Mainfunction_10ms();
    }
    ZZZ_Mainfunction_5ms();
}
```

So, if you need something to be run every 5, 10 or 20ms, you put these runnables into the corresponding tasks.

The old OSEK also had a notion of BASIC vs EXTENDED Tasks, where only extended tasks where able to react on OsEvents. This tasks might not run cyclically, but only on configured OsEvents. You would have an OS Waitpoint there, where the tasks is more or less stopped and only woken up by the OS on the arrival of an event. There are also OSALARM, which could either directly trigger the activation of a OsTask, or indirectly over an Event, so, you could e.g. wait on the same Waitpoint on both a cyclic event from an OsAlarm or an OsEvent set by something else e.g. by another task or from an ISR.

```
TASK(TASK_EXT)
{
    EventMaskType evt;
    for(;;) 
    {
        WaitEvent(EVT_XXX_START | EVT_YYY_START | EVT_YYY_FINISHED);
        GetEvent(TASK_EXT, &evt);
        // Start XXX if triggered, but YYY has reported to be finished
        if ((evt & (EVT_XXX_START | EVT_YYY_FINISHED) == (EVT_XXX_START | EVT_YYY_FINISHED))
        {
            ClearEvent(EVT_XXX_START);
            XXX_Start();
        }
        // Start YYY if triggered, will report later to start XXX
        if (evt & EVT_YYY_START)
        {
             ClearEvent(EVT_YYY_START);
             YYY_Start();
        }
    }
}
```

This direct handling of scheduling is now mostly done/generated within the RTE based on the events you have configured for your SWCs and the Event to Task Mapping etc.

Tasks are scheduled mainly by their priority, that's why they can be interrupted anytime by a higher priority taks. Exception here is, if you configure your OS and tasks to be not preemptive but cooperative. Then it might be necessary to also use Schedule() points in your code, to give up the CPU.

On bigger systems and also on MultiCore systems with an MultiCore OS, there will be higher nunbers of Tasks, because Tasks are bound to a Core, though the Tasks on different Cores run independently, except maybe for the Inter-Core-Synchronization. This can also have a negative performance impact (Spinlocks can stop the whole system)

e.g. there could be some Cyclic Tasks for normal BaseSW components and one specific only for Communication components (CAN Stack and Comm-Services).
We usually separate the communication part, since they need a certain cycle time like 5..10ms, since this cycle is used by the Comm-Stack for message transmission scheduling and also reception timeout monitoring.
Then there might be a task to handle the memory stack (Ea/Fls, Eep/Fee, NvM).
There might be also some kind of Event based Tasks to trigger certain HW-control and processing chains of measured data, since they might be put on different cores, and can be scheduled by start or finished events of each other.

On the other side, for all your cyclic tasks, you should also make sure, that the functions run within such task do not run longer than your task cycle, otherwise you get an OS Shutdown due to multiple activation of the same task, since your task is started again, before it actually finished. And you might have some constraints, that require some tasks to finish in your applications expected measurement cycle.

In safety relevant systems (ASIL-A .. ASIL-D) you'll also have at least one task fpr each safety-level to get freedome-from-interference. In AUTOSAR, you already specify that on the OSApplication which the tasks are assigned to, which also allows you to configure the MemoryProtection (e.g. WrAccess to memory partitions by QM, ASIL-A, ASIL-B application and tasks). That is then another part, the OS has to do at runtime, to reconfigure the MPU according to the OsApplications MemoryAccess settings.

But again, the more tasks you create, the higher the usage of RAM, ROM and runtime.

- RAM - runtime scheduling structures and different task stacks
- ROM - the actual task and event configurations
- Runtime - the context switches of the tasks and also the scheduling itself

Answer (score 4):

Formally you can have an infinite number of OsTasks. According to the spec. the configuration of the Os can have 0..* OsTask.
Apart from that the (OS) software uses data type TaskType for Task-Index variables. Therefore, if TaskType is of uint16 you could not have more than 65535 tasks.
Besides that, if you have a lot of tasks, you might re-think your design.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I'm wondering what is the common number of tasks used in AUTOSAR compliant systems? Did anyone discuss how many tasks are usually in an AUTOSAR compliant system?

Comment: In quite simple ECUs you may be fine with only one task. In more complex ECUs it's generally about 5-20. Of course this all depends on your application and architecture.

Comment: Thank you so much, Oliver, for your nice answer! I'm wondering if there is any reference (or document) that discusses the common number of tasks on an ECU? (I'm a researcher on real-time system. I'm looking for what is the reasonable number of tasks used for evaluating a systems.)

Comment: Practically you will not find more than 10-15 task in DAS/ADAS products. As it was explained by Oliver earlier, its about datatype of TaskType. Usually it is (uint8), I have seen 255 max tasks. Practically most optimal choice.